# How to find unique element here?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Below are the two html I am dealing with,

```
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;"><input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" style="width: 164px;" disabled=""><div class="v-filterselect v-disabled v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box" style="width: 205px;"><div class="v-filterselect-button"></div></div></div>


<div class="v-filterselect v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box" style="width: 205px;"><input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" style="width: 164px;"><div class="v-filterselect-button"></div></div>
```

I wanted to locate 2nd element which is a dropdown, but i cant find unique element in them

I used : `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[@class='v-filterselect v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box']//input[@type='text']").send_keys("AN08 - THJ Wijnegem")`

But its navigating to 1st html.. Can anybody help ?

Many Thanks

Comment: 1) <div style="float: left; margin-left: 0px;"><input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" style="width: 164px;" disabled=""><div class="v-filterselect v-disabled v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box" style="width: 205px;"><div class="v-filterselect-button"></div></div></div>

Comment: Edit your question. Don't paste code here

Comment: 2) <div class="v-filterselect v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box" style="width: 205px;"><input type="text" class="v-filterselect-input" style="width: 164px;"><div class="v-filterselect-button"></div></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can locate second one like this :

```
(//input[contains(@class, 'v-filterselect-input')])[2]
```

if there are two similar kind of element, you can even try with `[1]` cause I am not sure which one is actually first and which one is second.

**In code :**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//input[contains(@class, 'v-filterselect-input')])[2]").send_keys("AN08 - THJ Wijnegem")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your time.. but this is giving element not found exception

Comment: Can you share the entire error stack trace ?

Comment: File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"(//div[@class='v-filterselect v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box']//input[@type='text'])[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.124)

Answer (score 0):

The second element can be located and accessed with this XPath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='v-filterselect v-filterselect-gk-combo-box gk-combo-box']//input[@type='text'])[2]").send_keys("AN08 - THJ Wijnegem")
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for this, but this is giving element not found exception

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Comment: It wont be accessible :(

Comment: Well, I have to see the entire page HTML to help. Here I just used the information you have provided.